# Ruby - regular expression

Tags: ruby, regex

```
str1 = "M Rahim (C)(W): 61(97)S A Hasan: 51(68)"
str2 = "R Taylor (C): 76(160)B Watling: 16(26)"

puts format(str1) #=> "M Rahim (C)(W): 61(97)\nS A Hasan: 51(68)"
puts format(str2) #=> "R Taylor (C): 76(160)\nB Watling: 16(26)"
```

for getting these output what I need to do in `format()` function. I am not much familiar with regular expressions

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This might do the trick but it is hard to know with such a limited sample:

```
def format(s)
  s.sub(/\A(.*?:\s*\d+\(\d+\))/) { $1 + "\n" }
end
```

The main thing that looks for is `': 61(97)'` and `': 76(160)'` or, generally, a colon followed by zero or more whitespace characters followed by a number followed by a number within parentheses.

If you don't know how many entries are on each line then you can use [`scan`](https://ruby-doc.org/core/String.html#method-i-scan) to extract them and [`join`](https://ruby-doc.org/core/Array.html#method-i-join) to put them back together:

```
def format(s)
  s.scan(/.*?:\s*\d+\(\d+\)/).join("\n")
end
```

for example:

```
>> s = str1 + str2
=> "M Rahim (C)(W): 61(97)S A Hasan: 51(68)R Taylor (C): 76(160)B Watling: 16(26)"
>> s.scan(/.*?:\s*\d+\(\d+\)/).join("\n")
=> "M Rahim (C)(W): 61(97)\nS A Hasan: 51(68)\nR Taylor (C): 76(160)\nB Watling: 16(26)"
```

Comment: +1 I was working on a finding the `\(\d+\)` that was not at the end of a string, but this one is clearer (assuming there are exactly two data items per line).

Comment: @Ray: I'd probably try a `scan`/`join` approach (as in my update) if there could be multiple "entries" mashed into one line.

Answer (score 2):

Well here is a method that finds any `)` followed by a capital letter and inserts a newline after the `)`:

```
def format(s)
    s.gsub(/\)(?=[A-Z])/, ")\n")
end
```

The `/` starts the regular expression.

The `\)` matches any right parenthesis in the string.  The slash is needed because `)` has a special meaning in regular expressions, so it needs to be escaped.

The `(?=[A-Z])` is a positive [lookahead](http://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html) assertion, asserting the the parenthesis is followed by a capital letter.

The second `/` ends the regular expression.

Answer (score 1):

```
def format(string)
  string.sub(/(\d\))/, '\1' + "\n")
end

p format("M Rahim (C)(W): 61(97)S A Hasan: 51(68)") #=> "M Rahim (C)(W): 61(97)\nS A Hasan: 51(68)"
p format("R Taylor (C): 76(160)B Watling: 16(26)")  #=> "R Taylor (C): 76(160)\nB Watling: 16(26)"
```